# apply language translation to Android application

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I want to apply language translator to my application. in that json response data also being converted to selected language. for that localization is not useful for me because it only converts what i declare in resource file.

And google translator not provide unlimited word translation per day

Comment: Welcome to SO.Tick mark as right on answer if you seems anything work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a solution on this. I've got suggestions from my colleague, but I've not tested them if they work. Here is what they say:

- Use unicode for your data wherever it is stored.
- Send unicode data in json.
- Use a unicode font in your android app that converts the data to the local language on the fly.